# How to load multiple Backbone.js views on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, checkbox

I am new to Backbone.JS any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

The attached JS Fiddle only allows me to load 1 view/template out of the two i have written. Any help on how I can get both templates to display?

I tried the following but it doesn't work ...

```
var qualityBasedMaterialorService_view = new qualityBasedMaterialorService({
    el: $("#form_select") 
});
var valueBasedService_view = new valueBasedServiceView({ 
    el: $("#form_load") 
});
```

I have attempted to recreate my code on JSFIDDLE with some comments - hope this helps.

New JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/CertifiedNinja/WyZU3/

Please help

Luke

Comment: It is possible and doesn't need any particular thing. The code you posted doesn't help understanding why it wouldn't work at all. Can you reproduce the problem on a fiddle and send it here ?

Comment: The URL has now been added.

Comment: Your fiddle is a mess. Your HTML isn't event valid. Post something simple, right, and straight to your problem.

Comment: It has now been updated - it's a little better. SOrry I havent got my point accross very succintly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making your HTML valid made it "work".

From

```
<div id="form_select"><div>
<div id="form_load"></div>
```

To

```
<div id="form_select"></div>
<div id="form_load"></div>
```

**Close your divs properly.**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/WyZU3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

i your example your are initializing the el member as

```
valueBasedServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#form_load",
```

it should be

```
valueBasedServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#form_load"),
```

Also there were missing Underscore and Backbone reference. I updated the jsfiddle, now it half works. http://jsfiddle.net/WyZU3/2/

Comment: Hi Many thanks for the updated JS Fiddle. You definitely have half of it working. But thats the problem ideally I would have both templates being displayed on the page on load. Do you understand what I mean? Thanks Again